# Update a date in oracle statement

Tags: php

I am trying to update a `date` in update statement but the statement below is not working for me. Is this the correct syntax i am using?. It works perfectly in Insert part. Any help would be nice.

**statement:**

```
$Edate = $_POST['datee'];

"UPDATE Total SET EDATE = TO_DATE('$Edate', 'yyyy-mm-dd')"
```

Comment: Is that your actual working code?  If so, you're missing a closing double quote.

Comment: @Fred -ii yes with the exception of where clause.

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: showing no error with no update.

Comment: You're just quoting a string, why do you expect it could do more than, well, nothing?

Comment: @Martin you mean i should use this `$Edate` instead `'$Edate'`?

Comment: No, you really have to learn basics of PHP & Oracle first.

Comment: You said your insert code works: post it. Compare it with the update code. The code you've posted above doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: @bcmcfc just made it work. i used this `oci_bind_by_name($result, ':datee', $Edate);` :)